# Java Calculator GUI operations

Tags: java

There are 4 classes: `Main`, `GUI`, `Logic` and `Calculator`. I'm having difficulty making the Calculator class right, the first operation/calculation is giving me the wrong answer but the next one is right. I tried to create another variable (`fnum` and `snum`) for the first and second number but it didn't work. Do I need to modify the Logic class?

**main class**

```
class Main
{ 
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.display();
  }
}
```

**GUI class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GUI
{
  private static final int H = 400;       // Height of window pixels
  private static final int W = 500;       // Width  of window pixels

  private JLabel      theMes      = new JLabel();       // Message area
  private JTextArea   theOutput1  = new JTextArea();    // Input number area
  private JTextArea   theOutput2  = new JTextArea();    // Result area
  private JScrollPane theSP       = new JScrollPane();

  private ButtonPress onButtonPress = new ButtonPress();

  public void display()
  {
    JFrame rpc           = new JFrame();            // Window
    Container cp         = rpc.getContentPane();    // Content Pane
    Container rootWindow = (Container) rpc;         // Root Window
    cp.setLayout(null);                             // No layout manager
    rootWindow.setSize( W, H );                     // Size of Window

    String labels[] = {
        "7",  "8", "9", "", "CR", "+",
        "4",  "5", "6", "",  "=", "-",
        "1",  "2", "3", "",  "",  "*",
        "C",  "0", "", "",   "",  "/" };

    final int LABELS = labels.length;      // # Button Labels

    final int GAP   = 15;                  // Horizontal Gap

    final int HLAB  = 20;                  // Label
    final int SHLAB = GAP;
    final int EHLAB = SHLAB+HLAB;

    final int HTA1  = 30;                  // Output area 1
    final int SHTA1 = EHLAB + GAP;
    final int EHTA1 = SHTA1 + HTA1;

    final int HTA2  = 100;                 // Output area 2
    final int SHTA2 = EHTA1 + GAP;
    final int EHTA2 = SHTA2 + HTA2;

    final int HBUT  = 170;                 // Buttons
    final int SHBUT = EHTA2 + GAP;

    final int BNR  = 4,    BNC  = 6;       // number rows cols of buttons
    final int BW  = W/BNC, BH = HBUT/BNR;  // Size of landscape for button
    final int SBH = SHBUT, SBW = 7;        // Start position for buttons


    JButton buttons[] = new JButton[LABELS];

    Font font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20);      // Button font

    for ( int i=0; i<LABELS; i++ )
    {
      if ( labels[i].length() >= 1 )
      {
        buttons[i] = new JButton( labels[i] );
        final int col = i%BNC * BW, row = i/BNC * BH;
        buttons[i].setBounds( SBW+col, SBH+row, BW-20, BH-10 );
        buttons[i].addActionListener( onButtonPress );
        buttons[i].setFont( font );
        cp.add( buttons[i] );
      }
    }

    font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,14);         // Font is

    theMes.setBounds( 10, SHLAB, W-25, HLAB );     // Message area
    theMes.setText( "" );                          // Blank
    theOutput1.setFont( font );                    //  Uses font 
    cp.add( theMes );                              //  Add to canvas

    theOutput1.setBounds( 10, SHTA1, W-25, HTA1 ); // Input Area
    theOutput1.setText("");                        // Blank
    theOutput1.setFont( font );                    //  Uses font 
    cp.add( theOutput1 );                          //  Add to canvas

    font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,14);         // Font is

    theSP.setBounds( 10, SHTA2, W-25, HTA2 );      // Scrolling pane
    theOutput2.setText( "" );                      //  Blank
    theOutput2.setFont( font );                    //  Uses font  
    cp.add( theSP );                               //  Add to canvas
    theSP.getViewport().add( theOutput2 );         //  In TextArea
    rootWindow.setVisible( true );                 // Make visible

    theMes.setText( "Calculator" );                // Opening message
  }


  private Calculator calc = new Calculator();
  private Logic logic     = new Logic( calc );

  class ButtonPress implements ActionListener       // Listener
  {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )   // Interaction
    {
      String label = ae.getActionCommand();         // Button label  

      String info = logic.process( label);

      theOutput2.setText( "" );
      if ( info == null )
        theOutput2.append( "" + logic.getResult() );
      else
        theOutput2.append( info );

      theOutput1.setText( "" );
      theOutput1.append( "Number entered: " + logic.getNumber() );
    }
  }
}
```

**Logic class**

```
class Logic
{
  private enum  State { FIRST_NUMBER, SUBSEQUENT_NUMBER };
  private State state = State.FIRST_NUMBER;
  private long  number = 0;
  private char  op = ' ';
  private Calculator calc = null;


  public Logic( Calculator calculator )
  {
    calc = calculator;
  }

  public String process( String button )
  {
    String info = null;
    if ( button.length() == 1 )
    {
      char c = button.charAt(0);
      if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' )               // Digit
      {
        number = number * 10 + c-'0';           // Build number
      } else {
        switch ( c )
        {
          case 'C' : number = 0;
                     break;
          case '=' :
          case '+' : case '-' :
          case '*' : case '/' :
            switch ( state )
            {
              case FIRST_NUMBER:
                calc.setValue( number );
                state = State.SUBSEQUENT_NUMBER;
                break;
              case SUBSEQUENT_NUMBER:
                if ( op != '=' )
                  calc.evaluate( op, number );
                break;
            }
            op = c;  number = 0;
            break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if ( button.equals( "CR" ) )               // Clear Result
      {
        calc.reset(); number = 0; state = State.FIRST_NUMBER;
      }
    }

    return info;
  }

  public long getResult()
  {
    return calc.getValue();
  }

  public long getNumber()
  {
    return number;
  }
}
```

**Calculator class**

```
class Calculator
{
//Evaluate an arithmetic operation on the stored result
// E.g evaluate( '+',9) would add 9 to the stored result
// evaluate( '/',3) would divide the stored result
// by 3
// actions are '+'. '-', '*', '/'
//Note: if the operation is
// evaluate( '/',0 ) the result returned should be 0


long value;


public void evaluate( char action, long number )
 {

     if (action == '+'){
      value += Float.valueOf(number).floatValue();


     }

    else if (action == '-'){
      value -= Float.valueOf(number).floatValue();

    }

    else if (action == '*'){
      value *= Float.valueOf(number).floatValue();

    }

    else if (action == '/'){
      value /= Float.valueOf(number).floatValue();

    }

}
//Return the stored result
public long getValue()
   {
    return value;
    }

//Set the stored result to number
public void setValue( long number )
{

}

//Reset the stored number to 0
public void reset()
{
       if ( value != 0) value = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static Float valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException`

Comment: why is your setValue() method has no code. It should have this.value = number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you dont actually set the value in the `setValue` method:

```
//Set the stored result to number
public void setValue( long number )
{
    this.value = number;
}
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer has already been pointed out, here are some general pointers on your code:

1. You're already breaking things up by area, which is good.
2. You need to add `rpc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in `GUI`, otherwise your calculator class will *contine to run*, even **after** the "Exit" icon has been closed.
3. This line: `Container rootWindow = (Container) rpc;` is pointless, as `rpc` is already being referenced as a container.
4. Some of your variable names are completely mysterious (`HLAB`, `SHTA1`, `HTA2`?).  Always label things appropriately and descriptively.
5. You're using `long`s to store and display your values, but `float`s to perform the actual math.  This means that the program generates wierd results - `9 / 2 = 4`, for example.  In addition, counter to your commenting, `9 / 0 = 9223372036854775807`.  I recommend you generate the initial numbers ('Number entered') as a stacj of characters, and perform all math with `BigDecimal`.
6. You are deliberately ignoring layout managers, and then go to great lengths to manually position all your buttons/labels.  Unfortunately, this makes your application break if it's resized.  What you need to do is break up your display into several (nested) `JPanel`s, each with the appropriate layout manager.  There are IDEs and plugins that allow you to visually design such systems, if necessary.
7. You're executing everything in the swing event thread.  While it works here, it's not best practice, and can be one of the fastest ways to break or hang an application.  All graphical content creation and manipulation should be dispatched through the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater();`, including the creation of the main window.
8. You are currently parsing the labels of the buttons to chose the action to perform.  This does not deal with things like internationalization well.  Is time permits, look into using the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to encapsulate your behaviours.  You'll want at least two sets; one for putting digits on the stack, and one for performing calculations.  This also means that adding new operations (like a `pow` function) doesn't require code modification, merely adding the new behaviour (and button).

For further and future critique, post code on CodeReview!

Comment: for CodeReview +1, hmmm nice answer

Answer (score 0):

```
package Calculator;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Carl extends JFrame {

JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" ");
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
JButton button10 = new JButton("0");
JButton button11 = new JButton("+");
JButton button12 = new JButton("-");
JButton button13 = new JButton("*");
JButton button14 = new JButton("/");
JButton button15 = new JButton("=");
JButton button16 = new JButton("C");
JLabel blank1 = new JLabel("");
JLabel blank2 = new JLabel("");
JLabel blank3 = new JLabel("");
JLabel blank4 = new JLabel("");
Font times = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18);
int operation1;
int operation2;
int operation3;
int operation4;
String n1, n2;
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

public Carl() {
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Calculator");
    setSize(600, 600);
    button1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button6.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button7.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button8.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button9.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button10.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button11.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button12.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button13.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button14.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button15.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button16.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button5.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button6.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button7.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button8.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button9.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button10.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button11.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button12.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button13.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button14.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button15.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button16.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button1.setToolTipText("one");
    button2.setToolTipText("two");
    button3.setToolTipText("three");
    button4.setToolTipText("four");
    button5.setToolTipText("five");
    button6.setToolTipText("six");
    button7.setToolTipText("seven");
    button8.setToolTipText("eight");
    button9.setToolTipText("nine");
    button10.setToolTipText("zero");
    button11.setToolTipText("addition");
    button12.setToolTipText("subtraction");
    button13.setToolTipText("multiplication");
    button14.setToolTipText("division");
    button15.setToolTipText("equal");
    button16.setToolTipText("clear");
    button1.setFont(times);
    button2.setFont(times);
    button3.setFont(times);
    button4.setFont(times);
    button5.setFont(times);
    button6.setFont(times);
    button7.setFont(times);
    button8.setFont(times);
    button9.setFont(times);
    button10.setFont(times);
    button11.setFont(times);
    button12.setFont(times);
    button13.setFont(times);
    button14.setFont(times);
    button15.setFont(times);
    button16.setFont(times);
    label1.setFont(times);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 3, 2, 2));
    p1.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p1.add(label1);
    p1.add(text1);
    p1.add(blank3);
    p1.add(button7);
    p1.add(button8);
    p1.add(button9);
    p1.add(button11);
    p1.add(button4);
    p1.add(button5);
    p1.add(button6);
    p1.add(button12);
    p1.add(button1);
    p1.add(button2);
    p1.add(button3);
    p1.add(button13);
    p1.add(button10);
    p1.add(button16);
    p1.add(button15);
    p1.add(button14);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    button1.addActionListener(new Listener1());
    button2.addActionListener(new Listener2());
    button3.addActionListener(new Listener3());
    button4.addActionListener(new Listener4());
    button5.addActionListener(new Listener5());
    button6.addActionListener(new Listener6());
    button7.addActionListener(new Listener7());
    button8.addActionListener(new Listener8());
    button9.addActionListener(new Listener9());
    button10.addActionListener(new Listener0());
    button11.addActionListener(new ListenerAdd());
    button12.addActionListener(new ListenerSub());
    button13.addActionListener(new ListenerMul());
    button14.addActionListener(new ListenerDiv());
    button15.addActionListener(new ListenerEqual());
    button16.addActionListener(new ListenerClear());
    setVisible(true);

}

private class Listener1 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "1");
    }
}

private class Listener2 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "2");
    }
}

private class Listener3 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "3");
    }
}

private class Listener4 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "4");
    }
}

private class Listener5 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "5");
    }
}

private class Listener6 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "6");
    }
}

private class Listener7 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "7");
    }
}

private class Listener8 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent h) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "8");
    }
}

private class Listener9 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "9");
    }
}

private class Listener0 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent j) {
        n1 = text1.getText();
        text1.setText(n1 + "0");
    }
}

private class ListenerAdd implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent k) {
        n2 = text1.getText();
        operation1 = 1;
        text1.setText("");
    }
}

private class ListenerSub implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
        n2 = text1.getText();
        operation2 = 2;
        text1.setText("");
    }
}

private class ListenerMul implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent m) {
        n2 = text1.getText();
        operation3 = 3;
        text1.setText("");
    }
}

private class ListenerDiv implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent n) {
        n2 = text1.getText();
        operation4 = 4;
        text1.setText("");
    }
}

private class ListenerEqual implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o) {
        if (operation1 == 1) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(n2);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
            int sum = (a + b);
            String sum1 = Integer.toString(sum);
            text1.setText(sum1);
        } else {
            text1.getText();
        }
        if (operation2 == 2) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(n2);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
            int dif = (a - b);
            String dif1 = Integer.toString(dif);
            text1.setText(dif1);
        } else {
            text1.getText();
        }
        if (operation3 == 3) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(n2);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
            int product = (a * b);
            String product1 = Integer.toString(product);
            text1.setText(product1);
        } else {
            text1.getText();
        }
        if (operation4 == 4) {
            double a = Double.parseDouble(n2);
            double b = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText());
            double quo = (a / b);
            String quo1 = Double.toString(quo);
            text1.setText(quo1);
        } else {
            text1.getText();
        }
    }
}

private class ListenerClear implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) {
        text1.setText("");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Carl frame = new Carl();
}
}
```

Use this code..